# How to query date from 2 tables in a single select statement on condition that if first table doesnot return any data then 2 table data is populated

Tags: sql

Suppose i have TABLE_A(master) and Table_B(map).

i want to query data from TABLE_A with condition.

if no data is present in table_a then i want to query TABLE_B.

Answer (score 0):

```
If NOT Exists (select top 1 * from Table_A)  -- Here syste will check whether data is present in Table_A or Not. If Not then It will show data from Table_B other wise it will display the Else part.
Begin
   select * from Table_B
End
else
Begin 
   select * from Table_A
End
```